# How to fetch all World Stock Exchanges price from YQL

Tags: android, yql, yahoo-finance

I fetch Stock Data of particular stocks using YQL-yahoo finance API as below.

```
select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=INFY.BO,RELIANCE.NS,TCS.BO&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv' and columns='symbol,price,date,time,change,col1,high,low,col2'
```

But I want to fetch All World exchanges indices price.So i try like this,

```
select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BSESN&f=sl1d1t1' and columns='symbol,price,date,time'
```

I does not works.

1.How to fetch all World Stock Exchanges price from YQL-yahoo finance API? Is it possible to do?

2.Is it possible to fetch History stock data from YQL-yahoo finance API for a timeperiod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1.How to fetch all World Stock Exchanges price from YQL-yahoo finance API? Is it possible to do?*
The symbol for BSESN is wrong.  It should be `^BSESN` (Similarly you can try other stock exchanges eg: Taiwan `^TWII`)

The YQL query would be: 
`select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%5EBSESN&f=sl1d1t1' and columns='symbol,price,date,time'`
You can try the above query [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fs%3D%255EBSESN%26f%3Dsl1d1t1%27%20and%20columns%3D%27symbol%2Cprice%2Cdate%2Ctime%27&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys). You also need to encode the `^`.

In order to get the correct symbols, go to [Yahoo! Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com) site and search for the symbol. Searching for BSESN opens the BSE Sensex page and the symbol you need should be in the brackets. 
eg:`BSE SENSEX (^BSESN)`

*2.Is it possible to fetch History stock data from YQL-yahoo finance API for a timeperiod?*
This I am not sure how to do (not sure if the API's even support it). Take a look at [this](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) page. Might be helpful.

Comment: Wish I had more info on this. Will update the answer if I find anything.